# inserting member function ptr into a map

Tags: templates, c++17, static-polymorphism

**EDIT** delete formatting from code itself (bold).

**Edit 2** added the at the end of the answer the fix

I have the following code where I'm trying to create static polymorphism and template classes,
I'm trying to insert into a map in **Only one** of the derived types member function ptr.
the definition of the map is this:

```
std::map<std::string,void(derived::*)()> m_func;
```

and the insert command is this:

```
`m_func.insert(make_pair("yaodav",&derived::HelloWorld));`
```

and this is the whole code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <any>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <typeindex>
using namespace std;


template<class Derived>
class base
{
public:
    void clean()
    {
        cout << "I'm cleannig \n";
    }
    void process()
    {
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->setup();
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->run();
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->cleanup();
    }
};


class derived : public  base<derived> 
{
    friend class base<derived>;
    void setup() {
        m_func.insert(make_pair("yaodav",&derived::HelloWorld));
        cout << "derived setup \n"; }
    void run() { cout << "derived run \n"; }
    void cleanup() { cout << "derived cleanup \n"; }
    void HelloWorld() {cout << "hwllo from derived \n"; }
    std::map<std::string,void(derived::*)()> m_func;

};


class derived1 : public base<derived1> 
{
    friend class base<derived1>;
    void setup() {cout << "derived1 setup \n"; }
    void run() { cout << "derived1 run \n"; }
    void cleanup() { cout << "derived1 cleanup \n"; }
    void HelloWorld(){}
};

template <class T>
class Y{
 public:
 std::vector<std::any> m_vec;   

};


template <typename T>
class D:public Y<T>
{
    public:
    friend class Y<T>;
    void print()
    {
        for(auto& e: Y<T>::m_vec)
        {
             if(e.type()==typeid(base<derived1>*))
            {
                try {
                    auto* r = any_cast<base<derived1>*>(e);
                    r->process();
                }
                catch(const std::bad_any_cast& e) {
                    std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
                }
            }
            else
            {
                try {
                    auto *r = any_cast<base<derived> *>(e);
                    r->process();
                }
                catch(const std::bad_any_cast& e) {
                    std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
                }
            }

        }
    } 
};


int main()
{
        base<derived>* b =  new base<derived>;
        base<derived1>* c =  new base<derived1>;

        D<derived> y;
        y.m_vec.push_back(b);
        y.m_vec.push_back(c);
        y.print();
}
```

but when the insert function called (the bold section) I'm getting a Segmentation fault, it's like the m_func dos not exist when I'm running a debugger and I wont to print m_func I'm getting :

> here is no member or method named m_func

why is that happening and how to fix it

**The fix**

```
 base<derived>* b =  new derived;
 base<derived1>* c =  new derived1;
```

instead of

```
 base<derived>* b =  new base<derived>;
 base<derived1>* c =  new <derived1>;
```

Comment: @lubgr tnx,  fix it

Comment: You have a base class that takes its derived class as a template argument? Then you public friend class the base class? I hope this is just an experiment, because this is pretty bad and error-prone design... using `std::any` you're preventing any static code analysis (e.g. intellisense) of helping you fix this.

Comment: @JHBonarius  this design is for low latency program, where you wont to prevent the vTable and Cache miss. if you wont to see the lecture it from it on youtube  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vzDl0Q91MrM&t=173s

Comment: thx... doesn't look very fast... I will look into it... Meanwhile, did you understand the answer? `base<derived>* b =  new base<derived>;` needs to be `base<derived>* b =  new derived;`. But you have a memory leak. And missing a virtual destructor in `base`. Don't try complex stuff if the basis is not correct.

Comment: also, another nice presentation on overcoming inheritance: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PSxo85L2lC0

Comment: OK, watched the video... I refers to the [Curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)... It mentions nothing about `std::any`. You're missing the point and making it very complex again.

Comment: @JHBonarius  the 'std::any' it because other constraints that I have . and yes thank you  I understood the answer.

Comment: ... by using exception handling and std::any you're losing all the advantage of the CRTP. This is not low-latency code at all. You should consider reading about [Software Anti-patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern#Software_engineering) to see what kind of things you shouldn't do.

Comment: I know that it better not to use exception and `std::any` but like I wrote before I have some constraints that force me to use those tools. 
but thank you for the helpful links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is roughly equivalent to this:

```
base<derived>* b = new base<derived>;
b->process();
```

Inside `process`, there's `static_cast<Derived*>(this)` - but the instance of `base<derived>` that `b` points to is **not** in fact an instance of `derived`. You have instantiated `base<derived>` standalone, not as part of a `derived` instance. Your program never created an instance of `derived`, nor `derived1`. So you are trying to call a member function of an object that never existed, whereupon your program exhibits undefined behavior.

---

Even more streamlined version of your code would look like this:

```
class Base{};
class Derived : public Base {
public:
  void DoSomething() {};
};

int main() {
  Base* b = new Base;
  static_cast<Derived*>(b)->DoSomethind();  // undefined behavior here
}
```

This way, it should be clearer what's wrong.

Comment: I hope you mean `Base* b = new Derived;`... else this is UB... Oh, wait, that's what you are trying to point out...

Comment: @JHBonarius Added a comment to make it clearer still.